# How do I say "I wish I may, I wish I might" in Spanish?

Tags: expresiones

I am trying to translate this poem into Spanish, but am having trouble on the third line:

Star light, star bright,
First star I see tonight,
**I wish I may, I wish I might,**
Have this wish I wish tonight.

Does anyone know how to say "I wish I may, I wish I might" in Spanish? I will be forever grateful for your help!

Comment: That is quite hard to answer as most English speakers have trouble distinguishing _may_ from _might_ so it may not be clear what the song writer thinks it means. Perhaps you should edit to clarify what you think?

Comment: It is not very grammatical in English either. I wish I might is sort of, I wish I may is not. That said, this is a poem for kids. So, it has to rhyme. might has to rhyme with light, and tonight. The idea is: Que pueda este deseo cumplirse; Ojalá que se cumpla este deseo.

Answer (score 1):

- Ojalá (que) se me cumpla, ojalá (que) se me pudiera cumplir este deseo.
- Quisiera que se (me) cumpla, quisiera que se (me) pudiera cumplir este deseo (que estoy pidiendo esta noche/que pido...)

Answer (score 0):

The full translation could `¨Yo deseo que puedo, yo desearía poder"` could be shortened for aesthetics to: `Deseo que puedo, desearía poder`. Those are two different forms for the 1st person conditional. Kinda sad as well.

Comment: I wish I may have the wish I wish tonight. Is not yo deseo.